# Stata local macro not defined

Tags: stata, verbosity

Many times, I attempt to define a macro only to see that it was not created.

- My first question is: is there a better way to keep track of these failures than manually typing `macro list` after every single dubious `local mylocal ...` definition I attempt?
- Second, why does defining a local ever fail silently? Is there some way to enable warnings for this event?
- Third, the code below illustrates where this behavior frustrated me most recently: grabbing the position of a word in a string vector; decrementing the position by one; and grabbing the word in the corresponding (immediately preceding) position. Any pointers would be welcome.

.

```
local  cuts      0 15 32 50
local  mycut     32
local  myposn    : list posof "`mycut'" in cuts

// two methods that fail loudly:
local  mynewcut  : word ``myposn'-1' of cuts

local  mynewcut  : word `myposn'-1 of cuts


// five methods that fail silently, creating nothing:
local  mynewcut  : word `=`myposn'-1' of cuts // 1

scalar tmp = `myposn'
local  mynewcut  : word `=tmp-1' of cuts // 2

scalar tmp2 = tmp -1 // 3 
local mynewcut : word `=tmp2' of cuts

local mynewposn = `=`myposn'-1'
local  mynewcut  : word `mynewposn' of cuts // 4

local  mynewcut  : word `=`mynewposn'' of cuts // 5

// also fails silently (and is not what I'm looking for):
local  mysamecut : word `myposn' of cuts
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
local  cuts      0 15 32 50
local  mycut     32
local  myposn    : list posof "`mycut'" in cuts

local  mynewcut  : word `=`myposn'-1' of `cuts'
display "`mynewcut'"
```

You need to evaluate the arithmetic operation using `=`. You are also missing quotes when referring to local `cuts`.

Trying to use a macro that has not been defined is not considered an error by Stata. This is an element of language design. Also, note that (at least) one of your undesired syntaxes

```
local  mynewcut  : word `=`myposn'-1' of cuts
```

is not illegal, so care must be exercised in those cases. After the `of`, Stata is only expecting some string and `cuts` is consired a string. This will work just fine:

```
local  mynewcut  : word 2 of cuts cuts2 cuts3
display "`mynewcut'"
```

but maybe not as expected. Things change when the quotes are added. Stata now knows it has to do a macro substitution operation.

I usually take a good look at locals before putting them into "production". But you could use `assert`. For example:

```
local  cuts      0 15 32 50
local  mycut     32
local  myposn    : list posof "`mycut'" in cuts
display "`myposn'"

local  mynewcut  : word `=`myposn'-1' of cuts
display "`mynewcut'"

assert "`mynewcut'" != ""
```

Comment: Ah, duh, forgot quotes on my macro variable "cuts". Any advice on monitoring these silent failures?

Comment: Thank you, I will get in the habit of using `display` or `assert`. It's too bad so many quotation marks are required for such a (conceptually) simple check. That's interesting about how Stata parses whatever follows `word # of`.

Comment: I've lost track of the number of times I've been bitten by "quote issues".

Answer (score 3):

Roberto gave a good detailed answer, but in addition let's try an overview here. What's crucial is exactly what you understand by **fail** and whether there is any sense in which Stata might agree with you.

Blanking out an existing local macro and assigning an empty string to a (potential) local macro name have the same effect so far as Stata is concerned. If I go

```
local foo = 42 
local foo
```

or

```
local bar
```

the process is different in kind but the end result is similar. In the first case the local named `foo` disappears and the second case the local macro `bar` is never created. The second case is not futile, as (for example) a programmer often wants to make clear that a local macro is initially empty (except that's not quite possible) or that any previously created macro with that name is removed.

More concisely put, Stata doesn't distinguish, at least as far as the user is concerned, between an empty (local or global) macro and a macro that doesn't exist. This is less strange if you understand the definitions here to be inspired by operating system shells, rather than string processing languages.

But there is a useful consequence. The test

```
if "`bar'" != ""
```

is both a test for existence and a test for non-emptiness of the local macro `bar`, and it applies to macros with numeric characters too.

Furthermore, there may be cases in which you attempt to put a non-empty string into a macro, make some mistake so far as you are concerned, and end by assigning an empty string. That may be a programming mistake, but it's not illegal as far as Stata is concerned, as the examples above already imply.

Completeness is elusive here, but one more case is that a macro definition can be illegal for other reasons. Thus

```
local foo = lg(42)
```

will fail because there is no function `lg()`. On the other hand,

```
local foo lg(42)
```

will succeed so far as Stata is concerned because no evaluation is enforced and so Stata never has to work out `lg(42)`. The macro will just contain `lg(42)` as text.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful summary. Stata needn't regard a command as illegal to throw out a warning about it. Here, that would mean noting that `local foo my_dumb_attempt` has characters after "foo" and yet assigns an empty string to "foo". Stata hardly seems like a language for programmers, so I'd expect more hand-holding as far as that goes.

Comment: You are mixing technical questions with more personal or  subjective opinions, which might be fun to debate one to one but don't lend themselves easily to concise replies. Stata is a language in which many people are happy to program and long term too. Mata is an embedded language that's more like many other people's ideas of a programming language. Both are languages that are short on hand-holding or warnings. That could be a question in itself. Your specific example `local foo my_dumb_attempt` is perfectly legal; Stata programmers use such copying of text to macros all the time.

Comment: Fair enough. To clarify, by `my_dumb_attempt`, I meant one of the countless ways of arriving at an empty string silently, not literally typing or passing that command. I look forward to learning Mata.

Comment: OK, but back-quoted text tends to be taken literally here and facetious examples are also par for the course.